# MS Access Query to return zero if count is zero for month and year

Tags: ms-access

[image: Screenshot]

Data is AC_TYPE1, CountOfDEFECT, MonthCALOffset, MonthYear.

Some AC_TYPE1, have defects for EVERY month. No issues.
Some AC_TYPE1 have no defects for some months.
Need query to show zero for CountOfDEFECT when count is zero for these months.

MonthCALOffset is a numeric. Jun 2023 = -1, May 2023 = -2 ....
MonthYear is text.

I have a calendar table which has these MonthCALOffsets against dates.

See screenshot. 737-8 is fine. ATR72-600 has some months missing because count is zero.

My SQL query is:

```sql
SELECT qD1_1.AC_TYPE1, Count(qD1_1.DEFECT) AS CountOfDEFECT, qD1_1.MonthCALOffset, qD1_1.MonthYear
FROM qD1_1
WHERE (qD1_1.MonthCALOffset Between -12 And -1)
GROUP BY qD1_1.AC_TYPE1, qD1_1.MonthCALOffset, qD1_1.MonthYear;
```

Help greatly appreciated. There are many other queries with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a table `tblACType`, create a new table `tblMonthOffset` with one column as PK named `offset` of type Numeric Long and add it all the numbers -12 to -1. The you can query

```sql
SELECT
    allMonths.AC_TYPE,
    Nz(Count(qD1_1.DEFECT), 0) AS CountOfDEFECT,
    allMonths.offset AS MonthCALOffset,
    Nz(qD1_1.MonthYear, Format$(DateAdd("m", allMonths.offset,#2023-07-01#),"mmm-yy") AS MonthYear
FROM
    (SELECT tblACType.AC_Type, tblMonthOffset.offset
     FROM tblACType, tblMonthOffset) AS allMonths 
    LEFT JOIN qD1_1
        ON allMonths.AC_Type = qD1_1.AC_Type1 AND
           allMonths.offset = qD1_1.MonthCalOffset
GROUP BY allMonths.AC_TYPE, allMonths.offset
```

Explanation:

- The inner SELECT does not have a JOIN clause and therefore creates a Cartesian Product, i.e., all possible combinations of AC_Types and month offsets.
- Left joining this to the main table will produce a record for eavey type and every month with NULL columns for the missing records of the main table.
- The MonthCalOffsets will be missing for these records as well, therefore I added an expression calculating this value.

I am not sure whether the condition `WHERE qD1_1.MonthCALOffset Between -12 And -1` is required. If only offsets between -1 and 12 exist, there is not point in adding this condition.

Comment: The Cartesian "spark" of an idea fixed the issue. Eternally grateful!

Answer (score 0):

In a new query, you can use a *Cartesian* query to generate all the year-months, then left-join this to your existing query:

```sql
SELECT 
    T.AC_TYPE1, 
    Val(Nz([CountOfDEFECT])) AS CountOfDEFECTS, 
    T.MonthCALOffset,
    Format(DateAdd("m", T.MonthCALOffset, Date()), "mmm-yy") As MonthYear
    
FROM 
    (SELECT qD1_1.AC_TYPE1, Months.MonthCALOffset
    FROM qD1_1, 
        (SELECT DISTINCT -[Tens]-[Ones] AS MonthCALOffset, 10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) AS Tens, Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Ones
        FROM MSysObjects AS Uno, MSysObjects AS Deca)  AS Months
        GROUP BY qD1_1.AC_TYPE1, Months.MonthCALOffset
        HAVING (((Months.MonthCALOffset) Between -1 And -12)))  AS T 

LEFT JOIN 
    qD1_1 ON (T.MonthCALOffset = qD1_1.MonthCALOffset) AND (T.AC_TYPE1 = qD1_1.AC_TYPE1);
```

Comment: The Cartesian "spark" of an idea fixed the issue. Eternally grateful!